# Universal property of quotient group to get epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-spaces, universal-property

I know there are already answers to the question of the universal property of quotient groups. For example here: [Universal property of quotient group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354954/universal-property-of-quotient-group).

My question is now: If I have the homomorphism: $\phi: G \to G'$ and let H be $H\subset ker(\phi)$. Moreover I have the canonical projection $\pi: G \to G/H$. Due to the univeraly property of quotient groups there exists a unique homomorphism: $\bar{\phi}: G/H \to G'$.

Can I now say that: I know that $\pi$ is surjective. The homormophism $\phi$ is surjective iff $\bar{\phi}$ is surjective?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In fact, this has nothing to do with group theory. If you have a surjective map $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ and you have a map $g\colon B\longrightarrow C$, then $g$ is surjective if and only if $g\circ f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

In the situation displayed in the diagram below we have that $\varphi$ is surjective if and only if $\varphi'$ is surjective.

[image]

If $\varphi'$ is surjective, then $\varphi'\circ\pi$ is surjective because composition of surjective functions.

Conversely, if $\varphi$ is surjective, then $\varphi'$ is surjective as well.
This doesn't depends on the surjectivity of $\pi$.
For if $y'\in G'$ then there exists $x\in G$ such that $y'=\varphi(x)$, hence $y=(\varphi'\circ\pi)(x)\in\operatorname{Im}\varphi'$.